# Store multiple outputs from each iteration of a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, filepath

Given a fix path and a very limited directories from year. I'm trying to obtain each combination of path between this initial combination (*fixPath - year*) and the different, **non-fixed and non-equally quantity**, subdirectories contained in each combination of *fixPath - year*

```
fixPath <- "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example"
year <- 2008:2010
pathVector <- paste(fixPath, year, sep = "/")
pathVector
[1] "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2008" "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2009"
[3] "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2010"
```

My approach to solve this problem is use a for-loop:

1. Set the working directory with `setwd(pathVector[1])`
2. Scan the files (the subdirectories) with `list.files`in that working directory and obtain each combination with: `paste(pathVector[1], list.files(pathVector[1]), sep = "/")`
3. Store this combinations in a vector and proceed with the next iteration

...but **from each iteration of the loop I have a bunch of combinations and I can't figure out how to store more than one for each iteration**. Here is my code:

```
for (i in seq_along(pathVector)) {
setwd(pathVector[i])
# here I only obtain the combination of the last iteration
# and if I use pathFinal[i] I only obtain the first combination of each iteration 
pathFinal <- paste(pathVector[i], list.files(pathVector[i]), sep = "/")
# print give me all the combinations
print(pathFinal[i])
}
```

So, **how can store multiple values (combinations) from each iteration in a for loop?**

I want a vector that contain all the combinations, for example:

```
 "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2008/a"
 "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2008/z"
 "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2009/b"
 "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2009/z"
 "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2009/y"
 "C:/Users/calcazar/Desktop/example/2010/u"
```

Comment: does `list.files(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)` help with this task?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Any sugestion in how can applied `full.names = TRUE` and `recursive = TRUE`? because it doesn't work with `list.files(fixPath, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: `list.files(fixPath, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)`  Works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this do what you want?

```
pathFinal = NULL

for (i in seq_along(pathVector)) {
  setwd(pathVector[i])

  pathFinal <- c(pathFinal, paste(pathVector[i], list.files(pathVector[i]), sep = "/"))

  print(pathFinal[i])
}
```

Comment: the assign operator "c" does the job of encapsulate of all the combinations, but the print function only shows the combinations of the first iteration. By the way thanks for your answer!

Comment: Ok so we are halfway there! :) You would like to print in every iteration all the subdirectories? Because you can just print the paste argument (`paste(pathVector[i], list.files(pathVector[i]), sep = "/")` ). Or would you like to have a list that has for each iteration all the subdirectories?

Answer (score 2):

You might try to set up a vector beforehand and then use this part in your for loop:

```
append(VectorName, pathFinal[i])
```

you might try to include it in your existing code like this

```
pathFinal <- append(pathFinal, paste(pathVector[i], list.files(pathVector[i]), sep = "/"))
```

I haven't checked it, but it should add each new value to your desired vector. Also, I don't think you need to use `setwd()`.

Comment: or use the `foreach` library.

Comment: the append function does the job of encapsulate all the combinations in each iteration. You are right, the use of "setwd" is redundant. Thx!